# ruby error on windows 7 x64

Tags: ruby, windows-7-x64

install ruby 1.9.3, devkit, mingw
gem install rails work good, but when i create new rails app - have bundler error

```
D:/Programes/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': 193: %1 эх  ты хЄё  яЁшыюцхэшхь Win32.   - D:/Programes/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i386-mingw32/digest/sha1.so (LoadError)
    from D:/Programes/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from D:/Programes/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/definition.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from D:/Programes/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:138:in `definition'
    from D:/Programes/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/cli.rb:219:in `install'
    from D:/Programes/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
    from D:/Programes/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
    from D:/Programes/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:263:in `dispatch'
    from D:/Programes/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:386:in`start'
    from D:/Programes/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21/bin/bundle:13:in `<main>'
```

and commands like

```
D:\Work\ruby>gem help commands
ERROR:  Loading command: server (LoadError)
193: %1 эх  ты хЄё  яЁшыюцхэшхь Win32.   - D:/Programes/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i386-mingw32/digest/md5.so
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NameError)
uninitialized constant Gem::Commands::ServerCommand
```

file md5.so exists
what i forgot to do and may ruby don`t work on windows 7 x64?

Comment: ruby definitely works on 64bit windows. How did you say you installed ruby & devkit?

Comment: http://rubyinstaller.org/ ruby1.9.3-p0 released + devkit(https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/development-kit)

Answer (score 1):

I think you use cyrillic without `# encoding: UTF-8`, just add it to file where you use `эх  ты...`

P.S.: откуда вообще там кирилица?

Comment: If all that is relevant to the question, would you mind translating to english?

Comment: The cyrillic chars are from system output, 'not a valid Win32 application'.
May be openssl32 instead of 64bit, or some other lib?

Answer (score 0):

Also running Windows 7 x64, and I had this same problem crop up on me with 1.9.3-p0. Searched the web without success. Also tried copying in the "sha1.so" file from 1.9.2-p290 in case it was a problem with that particular library -- nope.

I'd suggest something about rubygems or bundler seems to break `require`, but the same bundler and rubygems code runs fine on 1.9.2. I get no problem running `require "digest/sha1"`
in my own bare test file with Ruby 1.9.3.

Reverting to Ruby 1.9.2-p290 fixed the problem for me for the moment.